# Rspec can't require file

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to learn rspec and write a hello-world program with it. But it seems like I can't require my class properly. It always shows undefined method error. This is my file structure:

```
├── lib
│   └── map.rb
└── spec
    ├── map_spec.rb
    └── spec_helper.rb
```

And my map_spec.rb file:

```
require 'map'

describe 'Map' do              
  it 'should iterate over array and return new array based on some simple addition' do
    expect([1,2,3]).map_sam_mario {|e| e+1}.to eq [2,3,4]
  end
end
```

This is my map.rb file:

```
class Array
  def map_sam_mario            
    [2,3,4]
  end
end
```

And when I do a rspec in the current directory, it always shows this error:

```
 NoMethodError:
       undefined method `map_sam_mario' for #   <RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget:0x007fad5a9e8270>
```

I was following a screencast and wrote the exactly the same code as the video. I don't know why this happened. I am using ruby 2.1.0 and rspec 3.0.3

Comment: `expect([1,2,3].map_sam_mario {|e| e+1}).to eq [2,3,4]`

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this line?

Comment: The code I've write is diff from yours,the monkey patch you write is called by `expect()` but not a `Array` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expect([1,2,3]).map_sam_mario {|e| e+1}.to eq [2,3,4]
```

You call `map_sam_mario` on `expect`. Of cause there is not such method because this is `RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget` class.

This line should be like this:

```
expect([1,2,3].map_sam_mario {|e| e+1}).to eq [2,3,4]
```

So `map_sam_mario` should be called on your `Array`.

This error has nothing to do with `require`.